# Generate multiple pdfs using FPDF class

Tags: php, fpdf

I have added a link on a page clicking on which generates a pdf and asks for download for which i have used fpdf class.

My new requirement is that clicking on the link should generate n number of pdf with different content and should ask for downloading these pdfs.

I am unable to find out the method to accomplish the same.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/ you'll find a nice php zip library. Imagine having an array of filenames like

```
$filenames = array(
    "file_01.txt",
    "file_02.doc",
    "file_03.pdf"
);
```

the code would look like this (untested)

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$archive = new PclZip('archive.zip');
foreach($filenames as $filename) {
    $result = $archive->add($filename);
    if($result==0) {
        die ("Error: " . $archive->errorInfo(true));
    }
}
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=archive.zip");
readfile("archive.zip");
```

Hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't send multiple files to user but you can generate them, pack with e.g. zip on server and send as one file.

Comment: thanks for replying is there any link for the same where i can check?

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to send your generated file to the browser is the `$pdf->Output()` - this will only allow you to send one generated pdf file. The only option to send more files is to zip them [1] and then send the package file.

[1] http://www.devco.net/archives/2005/05/24/creating_zip_files_with_php.php

Comment: but i want to generate 5 pdfs & how to add it to a single zip file

Comment: Simple : you create the PDFs one by one, add them to a single ZIP and finally send that ZIP as output. BTW You can use any archive format of course, it doesn't have to be ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

I used the flowing code in my php page:

```js
 if(isset($_GET['get_pdf'])){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_fixation WHERE postedby = '$name_user' ORDER BY fixation_id ASC ";
      $data_query = $hrmdb->select($query);
      if($data_query ){
        $i=0;
        while ($rows= $data_query ->fetch_assoc()) {
          $i++;
          $fixation_id = $rows['fixation_id']; 
echo "<script> window.open('allpdf/single_letter_fixation.php?fixation_id=".$fixation_id."','_blank');</script>";  
    }}
     }
```

Output option for pdf file in single_letter_fixation.php is:

```
$pdf->Output('D', $personal_file_number.pdf');
```

It works well.